# How to send synchronous post request with single button in GWT or GXT?

Tags: java, gwt, post, gxt

How can I send POST request with single button and without creating any FormPanel attached to it?

I want to send whole HashMap of data via POST for filling report and then return this report as XLS file stream, so the user should get "Save as..." dialog.

I can't do it by RequestBuilder as it creates AJAX requests and file can't be downloaded this way.

Maybe Sencha's GXT has a solution for this? It can fit here as well.

Comment: May I ask what's the problem with FormPanel?

Comment: @Thomas Broyer: I've got grid with data and buttons underneath. Each button does something completely different from others(close window, show grid selection on other Div, generate report from grid). So this would be wrong to wrap the FormPanel around all of those buttons. There are no typical form fields for user to input.

Comment: How about creating the FormPanel dynamically, just like you'd create a RequestBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've done. Send an AJAX POST. Your server should then send the URL of the XLS as a response. When the client (browser/GWT) receives the response, it opens up a hidden IFRAME with the XLS url. If the server sets the 'Content-Disposition' header to 'Attachment', the 'Save As' dialog will appear.

Comment: That involves storing on server my report data from first request to generate xls report stream in the second request. I want to avoid that

Comment: Huh? Whether you store date or not is irrelevant. The technique will still work. I must be missing some clarity in your problem?

Comment: If you want to limit it to one request, send back the XLS data and use a Data URI. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 0):

You can create `new FormPanel("_self")`. This form will return your XLS stream directly, not to the background iFrame.